# Windows 10 Data usage "bug". No internet usage report

Tags: networking, windows-10, internet

Since I upgraded to Windows 10, I had never used the built-in data usage report functionality (The one found in Settings → Network & Internet → Data Usage). However it seems awkward to me that the counter always stays at zero, despite being connected to internet and using some bandwidth.

In fact the data usage report seems to be buggy and does not give any usage statistics despite any source of internet connection. I have used different adpaters; ethernet, 4g/CDMA modem, wi-fi and ethernet but still there is no usage report and the counter is always at zero:

[image]    [image]

Is there explanation for this odd behaviour or a way to fix this?

<sub>Windows 10 Education x64bit</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use some useful third-party software to record data usage on Windows 10. You can get a better, detailed data usage report than the buggy Windows tool.

For example [Networx data monitor](https://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/) or [Glasswire](https://www.glasswire.com/features/#bandwidth)

> [**NetWorx**](https://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/) is a simple, yet versatile and powerful tool that helps you objectively evaluate your bandwidth consumption situation. You can use it to collect bandwidth usage data and measure the speed of your Internet or any other network connections.
>
> The program allows you to monitor all your network connections or just a specific network connection, such as Wireless or Mobile Broadband. The software also features an array of highly customisable visual and sound alerts. You can set it up to alert you when the network connection is down or when some suspicious activity — such as unusually heavy data flow — occurs. It can also automatically disconnect all dial-up connections and shut the system down.

The key features of this program include:

- Clear graphic and/or numeric display.
- Usage reports, exportable to a variety of file formats, including Excel, MS Word and HTML.
- Close supervision of uploads and downloads.
- Support of dial-up, ISDN, cable modems, ADSL, Ethernet cards, and more.

It has a portable version and a 30 day trial and costs $25

[image]

> [**GlassWire**](https://www.glasswire.com/features/#bandwidth) is an easy to use tool that can see your past and present network activity. Use the sliders to go back in time and analyze past network activity on the graph. Check your bandwidth usage by day, week, and month in detail with resolved hosts.

It has many features like Visual Network Monitoring, Bandwidth Usage
Monitor, and a lot more.

[image]

This software requires a license to operate fully, costing around $29 for a basic user.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please update this question to follow the guidelines provided [here](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/911683).

Comment: Ok fair enough, Besides costs, these seem pretty handy and I came across networx at some point, and it does what I want, but I was hoping not to install thirdy-party tools, but with the portable option, I will stick with networx

Answer (score 1):

The *Data Usage* report works as expected in Windows 10 Home (ver. 10.0.16299.125), shown below. The most likely cause of the issue is that [data collection for *Data Usage* is not enabled](https://winaero.com/blog/diagnostic-usage-data-windows-10/). Initial setting for data usage collection is made on installation, and can also be tweaked afterwards in the Registry, as well as Windows Privacy Settings. That said, though the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DataCollection` on the PC used for the image is set to 0, the report works!

[image: Win 10 Home Data Usage Report]

However, this does not seem to be a limitation of the Ed Win 10 version itself. You might check the following:

- If the PC you're using is at or from a school or other environment administered as a network, has *Group Policy* been set to prevent data collection?
- [Is the OS updated to the latest version](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/education/windows/windows-editions-for-education-customers)?
- Are there missing or corrupted files? [Use *DISM* and *SFC*](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026529/windows-10-using-system-file-checker) to detect and fix an issue.

BTW, there are third-party tools such as free [Glasswire](https://www.glasswire.com/) that produce *detailed* reports of network usage, including application and IP addresses.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I checked the registry key and still set at zero, I also ran `sfc` and `dism` commands but no changes. Anything I am missing?